# Wrapping class to another classloader with ByteBuddy

Tags: java, java-8, classloader, byte-buddy, bytecode-manipulation

I'm implementing an engine that encapsulates all code executed in an isolated classloader. I want to create a Logback Appender to retain all log from the code that will run on my engine.

For that I'm trying to use ByteBuddy.

```
  protected void append(LoggingEvent event) {
    System.out.println(event);
  }

  @Override
  protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    if (name.equals("io.vepo.logger.MyAppender")) {
      return new ByteBuddy().with((TypeDescription superClass) -> name)
                            .subclass(
                                TypeDescription.Generic.Builder.parameterizedType(
                                    Class.forName("ch.qos.logback.core.UnsynchronizedAppenderBase", false, this),
                                    Class.forName("ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent", false, this))
                                                               .build())
                            .method(ElementMatchers.named("append"))
                            .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(this).withAssigner((source, target, typing) -> StackManipulation.Trivial.INSTANCE))
                            .make()
                            .load(this, ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.INJECTION)
                            .getLoaded();
    } else {
      return super.findClass(name);
    }
  }
```

How can I implement the `Assigner` to cast the LogginEvent to my main classloader?

Comment: Can explain what you want to do in more detail? Are you trying to do dynamic assignment? In this case, use the `Assigner.DEFAULT` with `Assigner.Typing.DYNAMIC`.